# I want to build an advanced query in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-query-builder

I want to build a query nested in codeigniter

here is the  my controller

```
    public function advancedSearch(){
        if (!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
            redirect('main/login', 'refresh');
        }
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $data['code'] = $session_data['code'];

        $start = $this->input->post('start');
        $end =$this->input->post('end');
        $ticket = $this->input->post('ticket');
        $type =$this->input->post('type');
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('table');

        if ($start && $end) {
            $this->db->where('date >=',$start);
            $this->db->where('date <=',$end);
        } else if ($ticket) {
                $this->db->where('ticket','yes');
        } else if ($type) {
            $this->db->where('type',$type);
        }
        $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
      $data['data'] = $query->result();
    }
//print_r($data);
        $this->load->view('advanced-search',$data);
```

with this code I just get the first input a click and search, If I click just ticket I get the `$this->db->where('ticket','yes');` I hope I explained well.

Greetings

Comment: I hope I understood your question... are you not missing || or && in if conditions... like If( (! empty($start) && ! empty($end) ), something liek this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*instead of using `if else` use it with only `if` with `empty` check*

```
if ( ! empty($start)) 
{
  $this->db->where('date >=',$start);
} 
if (! empty($end))
{
  $this->db->where('date <=',$end);
}
if (! empty($ticket)) 
{
  $this->db->where('ticket','yes');
}
if (! empty($type)) 
{
   $this->db->where('type',$type);
}

$query = $this->db->get();

if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
{
  $data['data'] = $query->result();
}
//print_r($data);
$this->load->view('advanced-search',$data);
```